# How to Generate Adjacent Indecies w/ NumPy

Tags: python, numpy

So I'm trying to generate a list of possible adjacent movements within a 3d array (preferebly n-dimensional).

What I have works as it's supposed to, but I was wondering if there's a more numpythonic way to do so.

```
def adjacents(loc, bounds):
    adj = []
    bounds = np.array(bounds) - 1

    if loc[0] > 0:
        adj.append((-1, 0, 0))
    if loc[1] > 0:
        adj.append((0, -1, 0))
    if loc[2] > 0:
        adj.append((0, 0, -1))

    if loc[0] < bounds[0]:
        adj.append((1, 0, 0))
    if loc[1] < bounds[1]:
        adj.append((0, 1, 0))
    if loc[2] < bounds[2]:
        adj.append((0, 0, 1))

    return np.array(adj)
```

Here are some example outputs:

```
adjacents((0, 0, 0), (10, 10, 10)) 

= [[1 0 0]
   [0 1 0]
   [0 0 1]]

adjacents((9, 9, 9), (10, 10, 10))

= [[-1  0  0]
   [ 0 -1  0]
   [ 0  0 -1]]

adjacents((5, 5, 5), (10, 10, 10))

= [[-1  0  0]
   [ 0 -1  0]
   [ 0  0 -1]
   [ 1  0  0]
   [ 0  1  0]
   [ 0  0  1]]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an alternative which is vectorized and uses a constant, prepopulated array:

```
# all possible moves
_moves = np.array([
        [-1, 0, 0],
        [ 0,-1, 0],
        [ 0, 0,-1],
        [ 1, 0, 0],
        [ 0, 1, 0],
        [ 0, 0, 1]])

def adjacents(loc, bounds):
    loc = np.asarray(loc)
    bounds = np.asarray(bounds)
    mask = np.concatenate((loc > 0, loc < bounds - 1))
    return _moves[mask]
```

This uses `asarray()` instead of `array()` because it avoids copying if the input happens to be an array already.  Then `mask` is constructed as an array of six bools corresponding to the original six `if` conditions.  Finally, the appropriate rows of the constant data `_moves` are returned.

**But what about performance?**

The vectorized approach above, while it will appeal to some, actually runs only half as fast as the original.  If it's performance you're after, the best simple change you can make is to remove the line `bounds = np.array(bounds) - 1` and subtract 1 inside each of the last three `if` conditions.  That gives you a 2x speedup (because it avoids creating an unnecessary array).